# Create result from excel into TFS

Tags: tfs, azure-devops

I want to create result in TFS through an excel sheet. I need to have different iterations and my excel contains individual step results in each and every row.

Comment: Any background that makes you want to use excel to create the test result?

Comment: It is basically that i have all my result stored in excel for each steps and each iterations i just need to upload them to VSO, iteration by iteration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is related to offline test execution, however this feature is still in planning process. Refer to this link for details: http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-team-services/suggestions/3596154-offline-test-execution-allow-users-to-execute-tes

For now, I would recommend you to use Microsoft Test Manager to run the test. If you do want to do it via excel, you could save the test result in excel and then develop some code to read the test result information in the excel file and import the test result via TFS Test Management API. For the instruction about TFS TestManagement API, check [this link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.testmanagement.client.aspx) and [this link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/aseemb/archive/2012/08/07/code-snippets-on-test-management-apis.aspx) for details.